# How to set ORecordConflictStrategy on a specific class in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

Using the java API I can set the conflict strategy at the storage level g.setConflictStrategy but how can I set it to a class only like I can do using studio ? Thanks for any link to specific documentation.

Documentation as SQL can be found in ALTER CLUSTER but where is the Java approach ?

Comment: Which version of OrientDb are you using ?

Comment: You could see the documentation http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Alter-Database.html. To change strategy at database level you could use ALTER DATABASE CONFLICTSTRATEGY yourStrategy

Comment: I'm using orient 2.1 the documentation is in Alter Cluster but it's only for the SQL command I want to use the Java api to configure it. Any idea ?